# PHP SOAP SoapClient parameters

Tags: php, soap

I am brand new to SOAP with PHP (and SOAP in general).  I am having trouble with the SoapClient class.  It takes four parameters (request, location, action, version), but I really don't know what those should be as they pertain to the web service I'm trying to use.

See

http://wiki.agemni.com/Getting_Started/APIs/Agemni_CMS_Sync
and
http://www.agemni.com/_anet/ADBAccess.asmx?op=getCMSTables

Here is my best guess:

```
$wsdl = 'http://www.agemni.com/_anet/ADBAccess.asmx?WSDL';

$action = 'http://webservice.agemni.com/getCMSTables';
$request = 'POST /_anet/ADBAccess.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: www.agemni.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 10000
SOAPAction: "http://webservice.agemni.com/getCMSTables"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <getCMSTables xmlns="http://webservice.agemni.com/getCMSTables" />
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>"
';
$location = 'http://www.agemni.com/_anet/ADBAccess.asmx';
$version ='1';


$client = new SoapClient($wsdl);
$response = $client->__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version);
```

I'm not asking for anyone to do this for me, but if you could help clarify what $action, $request, and $location should be (pretty sure $version is just an int 1 or 2) I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you don't want to deal with the details of the request and you have the WSDL file, you don't need to set those parameters. Just instantiate with the path of the WSDL file and it suppose to contain everything else. The you just call

```
$response = $client->getCMSTables();
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php

Comment: Sweet!  Thank you.  In this particular case, you wouldn't happen to know how by glancing at the doc how I prove that I've logged in?

Comment: You mean the doc of Agemni? Prove that you logged in where? I think this is your friend here: http://wiki.agemni.com/Getting_Started/APIs/Agemni_CMS_Sync#agLogin

Comment: Indeed it is.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @ManoKovacs, What if you are forced to deal with the details?  I have to override the SoapClient class and set those manually due to a poorly coded api.  Do you happen to have the answer to the original question.  How do you find out how to assemble the location and action strings?